How to change the value of a variable defined outside the function in APL?
I am a beginner in APL (I use dyalog APL) and I want to change the value of a variable defined outside the function.
I've tried this function but marks_list is still empty after calling it:
Accessibilityset←{
    (⍴marks_list)=0 : marks_list←⍺
    marks_list
}


⊢←
That is,
Accessibilityset←{ (⍴marks_list)=0 : marks_list⊢←⍺ marks_list }

Note the ⊢ to the left of ←.
This is actually augmented (in APL lingo, known as modified) assignment, which you can think of as marks_list←marks_list⊢⍺ marks_list and therefore "forces" usage (and replacement) of the existing value, rather than creating a new, and thus automatically local, assignment.

Shameless plug: One can find this and many other things using APLcart. (I'm its creator.)
